# Equation for "$a$ is greater than $b$ by $40\%$"

Tags: percentages

Most people answer
$$
a = b + \frac{40}{100}b
$$

but I think this should also be right
$$
a - \frac{40}{100}a = b
$$
Is one of them wrong or both are correct?
Or the statement is lacking details of 40% of who (b or a).
Help me solve this question. Thanks.

Comment: Technically I would say it is lacking detail, grammatically I would say the first one.

Comment: "equation is greater" makes no sense. The value of a is greater than b by 40% makes sense

Comment: "*by 40%*" is not specific enough.  If it were clarified we would specify "*by 40%* **of b**" or "*by 40%* **of a**" or even "*by 40%* **of c**" for some other value $c$ and this would remove all ambiguity.  That said, the phrase without clarification does sadly appear in everyday language at times.  Usually in such a case, "*of b*" is intended.

Comment: @miracle173 I think the OP means something like: The equation for "a is 40% greater than b".

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes, that is possible. I will edit the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing is not clear. Let me rephrase:

$$\textrm{"a is greater than b by 40%"}$$

Let start with the untrue equality $a=b\quad(1) $.

At the moment the LHS is greater than the RHS by $40\%$. To obtain an equality we add $40\%$ on the right side.

$$a=b+0.4\cdot b\Rightarrow \boxed{a=1.4b}$$

Next we can set up an equation for $\textrm{"b is smaller than a by 40%"}$. If we look at $(1)$ we have to subtract $40\%$ at the left side to obtain a true equality.

$$a-0.4a=b\Rightarrow \boxed{0.6a=b}$$
It is worth to notice that this two equations are not equivalent (equal).

Answer (score 1):

This phrase always means that $a$ is $100$% of $b$ plus $40$% of $b$. Thus, your first thought is correct.